# is sqlserver.exe has stopped working related with certain setup issue after my recent upgrade?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I am constantly experiencing this "sqlserver.exe has stopped working" error message. Does it means certain outage or infra down happened in my system? Also I did not see any Error:824 or Error 823 msgs.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should uninstall your sqlserver and reinstall again.